# How to split linestrings into their individual segments according to every N points?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I asked a similar question a few days ago，
[PostGIS: how to split linestrings into their individual segments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70491702/17770516)

Hut further, I want to know more, if I want to split a line into a set of line segments according to every `N` points，how can I do this?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (gid int, geom geometry(linestring,4326));

INSERT INTO t VALUES
(1,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(1 1,2 2,3 3,4 4,5 5,6 6,7 7,8 8,9 9)'),
(2,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(1 1,2 2, 3 3, 4 4,5 5)'),
(3,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2)');
```

If `N=3` ,then I hope the result is like this:

```
MultiLineString( (1 1, 2 2, 3 3), (4 4, 5 5, 6 6), (7 7, 8 8, 9 9) )
MultiLineString( (1 1, 2 2, 3 3), (4 4, 5 5) )
MultiLineString( (1 1, 2 2) )
```

And further, if I want to reverse the operation, merge line segments into one line, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ST_MakeLine` as a function and change the window accordingly, e.g. `CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING` for the current row and the next two:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT gid, ST_MakeLine(j.geom) OVER w AS line
  FROM t, ST_DumpPoints(geom) j (path,geom)
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY gid ORDER BY j.path
               ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING)
)
SELECT gid, ST_AsText(ST_Collect(line)) AS geom FROM j
GROUP BY gid;
```

If you wish to rather split the LineStrings in 3 points chuncks, consider using PL/pgSQL:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
  i record; j record;
  line_partition geometry(linestring,4326) := 'SRID=4326;LINESTRING EMPTY';
  multiline geometry(multilinestring,4326) := 'SRID=4326;MULTILINESTRING EMPTY';
BEGIN
  FOR i IN SELECT gid,geom AS geom FROM t LOOP       
    FOR j IN SELECT * FROM ST_DumpPoints(i.geom) p (path,point) LOOP
      
      line_partition:=ST_MakeLine(line_partition,j.point);       
      
      IF ST_NumPoints(line_partition)=3  THEN
        multiline := ST_Union(multiline,ST_Multi(line_partition));
        line_partition := 'SRID=4326;LINESTRING EMPTY';
      END IF;       
                
    END LOOP;

    IF ST_NumPoints(line_partition)<3 THEN 
      multiline := ST_Union(multiline,ST_Multi(line_partition));      
      line_partition := 'SRID=4326;LINESTRING EMPTY';
    END IF;
        
    INSERT INTO t2 (gid,geom) VALUES (i.gid,multiline);
    multiline := 'SRID=4326;MULTILINESTRING EMPTY';
    
  END LOOP;      
END;
$$;
```

To reverse the operation, assuming you stored this information in a another table, just use `ST_MakeLine` with a `GROUP BY gid`

```
SELECT gid, ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(DISTINCT j.geom))
FROM t2,ST_DumpPoints(geom) j (path,geom)
GROUP BY gid;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d75da9ef23bd822f5522556adce3093f)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! but the result is : MULTILINESTRING((1 1,2 2,3 3),(2 2,3 3,4 4),(3 3,4 4,5 5),(4 4,5 5,6 6),(5 5,6 6,7 7),(6 6,7 7,8 8),(7 7,8 8,9 9),(8 8,9 9),(9 9)) ,not MultiLineString( (1 1, 2 2, 3 3), (4 4, 5 5, 6 6), (7 7, 8 8, 9 9) ) , It's not the result i want

Comment: @Anders could you please check if this is what you want? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=af8133eeaa306f2670179263b1a03aeb